# Undefined behavior with 2d array of struct C

Tags: c, csv, multidimensional-array, struct, undefined-behavior

I have a 2d array of structs that I am assigning strings to, here is my struct.

```
struct node {
  char* value;
};
```

Here is my allocation (I am new to C so I am not sure if it is right) but there will always be 35 columns but there could be millions of rows.( I just had it at 3 for now for testing)

```
const int rows=3;
    struct node ** arrayofnodes[rows][35];
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(test * sizeof array[0]);
    for(int j=0; j<35; j++) array[i][j] = malloc(sizeof array[0][0]);
}
```

I then read in character by character from a csv file and have a temp string, and assign the value of the temp to the position I want by using this below.

```
//int row and count are defined in my while loop I have for counting commas(or what col I am on) then new lines for the rows 
arrayofnodes[row][count]->value=strdup(temp);
   printf("%s  \n", arrayofnodes[row][count]->value);
   printf("%d %d \n",row, count );
```

When I assign like the way above it seems to work. I added these print statements in to make sure it was assigning the right values.

For example above would print out something like

> ```
> Red
> 0 0
> ```

And this is correct for that position.

But then after I do all of my assigning. I placed a print statement `printf("%s  \n", arrayofnodes[0][0]->value);` to test if I can retrieve the 1st value as shown above which should be "Red".

In my terminal it outputs "@`??"  or "@Pz?" or just any random output. I have tried this for a bunch of different positions besides 0,0, but they all get the same outcome. I guess I am just confused why the print statements work right after I assign them, but not at the end of my code when I call them later.

Comment: What is `test`?

Comment: @BradyDean I just edited the post "test" in the malloc was supposed to be "rows" I had it as test in my original code, copy past error, sorry

Comment: are `array` and `arrayofnodes` the same thing?

Comment: your last paragraph is difficult to read and follow. Could you structure it a bit?

Comment: I havent used arrays like this in C in awhile but because you have a dynamic number of rows, shouldn't `arrayofnodes` be dynamically allocated? The first subscript should give rows but in your code it gives the column index?

Comment: @bruceg yes they are, another typo I'm sorry just fixed it

Comment: @bolov just re worded

Comment: @BradyDean The rows aren't going to be dynamic I know how many rows there are its over a million though so for the begging of my code I'm just testing it with the 1st few rows.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it looks like you're trying to do. You will need to scan your csv file and compute the number of rows required, then populate the values however you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  char* value;
};

int main() {
  const int rows = 3; // you will need to compute this beforehand
  const int columns = 35;

  struct node** arrayofnodes = malloc(rows * sizeof(struct node*));

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    arrayofnodes[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(struct node));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
      arrayofnodes[i][j].value = malloc(...);
      strcpy(arrayofnodes[i][j].value, ...); // etc..
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
      free(arrayofnodes[i][j].value);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    free(arrayofnodes[i]);
  }

  free(arrayofnodes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid overcomplicated allocation by using constant size inside the structure:

```
struct OneRow
{
    char Value[35];
}

const int Rows=3;

OneRow *MyArray=NULL;

MyArray = (OneRow*) malloc (Rows*sizeof(OneRow));
```

You can now access each element (character) or a whole string as

```
MyArray[rownumber].Value[colnumber] = …
strcpy (MyArray[rownumber].Value, "I'm_shorter_than_35"); //34 chars max + null-term
```

Comment: My "value" I am assigning is a string or array of chars and I thought you couldn't store a string like "red" as postion char[0] unless you made it a pointer.